# How to move text with absolute position to centre of the parent div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to coding and I'm using bootstrap 4.
I want to overlap text with image and align it to the centre, here's the code...please help

## HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid front_page">
<img src="images/front_page_img.jpg" alt="front_page_image" class="front_page_img">
<div class="front_page_brand">
  <h1>T.A.C.S.</h1>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}

/* FRONT PAGE */
.front_page {
  position: relative;
}
.front_page_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.front_page_brand {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you would need to do is flex the parent container and `justify-content: center;`. Then, with your position already being absolute, it will overlap the image. Check out the code snippet below.

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}

/* FRONT PAGE */
.front_page {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.front_page_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.front_page_brand {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid front_page">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/400/000/fff" alt="front_page_image" class="front_page_img">
<div class="front_page_brand">
  <h1>T.A.C.S.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.front_page_brand {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```